# Max flow with a minimal in-degree objective on certain nodes (for edges with non-zero flow)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, combinatorics, network-flow

**The following a small-scale example meant to illustrate the general problem**

Suppose we have $n = 60$ marbles that we want to distribute into 3 bowls, $B = \{bowl_1, bowl_2, bowl_3\}$

The marbles can take the distinct colors $C = \{red, yellow, blue, green\}$ where we have: $n_{red} = 15$, $n_{yellow} = 10$, $n_{blue} = 20$, and $n_{green} = 15$.
The bowls have the marble capacities: $c_1 = 15$, $c_2 = 20$, and $c_3 = 25$.

The general distribution of marbles into bowls can be formulated as max flow problem via the flow network below, marble colors are the nodes (R), (Y), (B), and (G), while the bowls are the nodes (1), (2), (3).

Now, we introduce the additional objective that the **number of distinct colors in each bowl - summed over all bowls - should be minimized**.

This corresponds to minimizing the sum of the in-degrees of nodes (1), (2), and (3) - counting only the incoming edges with non-zero flow.

I attempt to formalize the objective function to minimize, where $1_{f(color,bowl)>0}(f)$ is an indicator function of non-zero flow for a given flow $f$ in the flow network.
$Obj(f) = \sum_{bowl \in B} \sum_{color \in C}(1_{f(color,bowl)>0}(f))$

Is there a general approach for solving this kind of problem?

[image]

Comment: The objective is not clear. What if you can't simultaneously minimize the in-degree of all the nodes of interest? Perhaps you interested in minimizing the *sum* or the *maximum*  of these in-degrees?

Comment: Have you tried to formulate it as an LP?

Comment: For multiple commodities with integer flows, the problem is possibly NP-hard.   Check out the _Multi-commodity circulation_ problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into LP and the Multi-commodity circulation problem